# JQuery not handling ajax form submissions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that when submitted, will return a success message and a new form with a new ID. The example of this is that you enter a postcode to calculate a distance to a certain area, and then once that form has been submitted, a change box will appear.

```
$("#PostcodeForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#PostcodeError').text(" ");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Scripts/Scripts.php",
        data: {Type:"SavePostcode",Postcode:$('#Postcode').val(),Slug:"<?php if(isset($_GET['ID'])){echo $_GET['ID'];}else{echo "None";}?>"},
        success: function(response) {
            if(response=="Error"){
                $('#PostcodeError').text("That postcode could not be found. Please use the entire postcode and try again.");
            }else{
                $('#DistanceContent').slideUp("400", function() {
                    $('#DistanceContent').html(response).slideDown();
                });
            }

        }
    });
    return false();
});

$("#PostcodeChangeForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Scripts/Scripts.php",
        data: {Type:"ChangePostcode"},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#DistanceContent').slideUp("400", function() {
                $(this).html("Enter your postcode to see how far away this unit is!<br/><form method=\"post\" id=\"PostcodeForm\">Postcode: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Postcode\" id=\"Postcode\" maxlength=\"8\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"PostcodeSubmit\" id=\"PostcodeSubmit\" value=\"Calculate!\" /></form><span id=\"PostcodeError\"></span>").slideDown();
            });
        }
    });
    return false();
});
```

The response within the first submission is:

```
 "6 miles, as the crow flies, from POSTCODE.<br/><form method=\"post\" id=\"PostcodeChangeForm\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"PostcodeChange\" id=\"PostcodeChange\" value=\"Change the Postcode!\" /></form>
```

My original html code is:

```
<div class="Widget DistanceWidget">
                <span class="Title">Distance:</span>
                <span class="Content" id="DistanceContent">
                Enter your postcode to see how far away this unit is!<br/>
                    <form method="post" id="PostcodeForm">
                        Postcode: <input type="text" name="Postcode" id="Postcode" maxlength="8" />
                        <input type="submit" name="PostcodeSubmit" id="PostcodeSubmit" value="Calculate!" />
                    </form>
                    <span id="PostcodeError"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Whats this `return false();`?? remove it you're already preventing windows default behaviour calling `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: What's the problem?  What indication do you have that something is wrong?  If I were to *guess* I highly suspect that you're never binding the `submit` handler to your second form.  It looks like you're trying to bind the handler once when the page loads, but that element doesn't exist until after user interaction.

Comment: `return false()` is the most effective way to prevent event from happening? Prevent everything at all.

Comment: @dfsq `return false()` will generate `Illegal return statement`and is not correct thats why i pointed out.

Comment: @RahilWazir Sorry, it was sarcasm. SyntaxError would *prevent* further code from running.

Comment: check this part `$_GET['ID'];}else{echo "None";}?>"}` you should keep using single quotes

Answer (score 1):

To bind event after the ajax response, just use `$(document).on( ... )` [Read here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You can use like this

```
$(document).on('submit', '#PostcodeChangeForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Your code
    ...
});
```

Full Code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#PostcodeChangeForm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        //Either use this or return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Scripts/Scripts.php",
        data: {Type:"ChangePostcode"},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#DistanceContent').slideUp("400", function() {
                $(this).html("Enter your postcode to see how far away this unit is!<br/><form method=\"post\" id=\"PostcodeForm\">Postcode: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Postcode\" id=\"Postcode\" maxlength=\"8\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"PostcodeSubmit\" id=\"PostcodeSubmit\" value=\"Calculate!\" /></form><span id=\"PostcodeError\"></span>").slideDown();
            });
        }
    });
    return false();            //Either use this or e.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the second form after an Ajax response, the element is not there when you bind `$("#PostcodeChangeForm").submit` So it attaches no events. You need to bind that event when you add the form. OR you can learn to use event bubbling with `on()`

Bind after

```
$(this).html("Enter...");
$("#PostcodeChangeForm").submit(function (e) { ...
```

Or using on:

```
$('#DistanceContent').on("submit", "#PostcodeChangeForm", function (e) {
    /* code here
});
```

Comment: How do I bind it after the response then?